# wordpress creating post automatically from images name

Tags: wordpress

my wordpress site creating post automatically from images name and also got index in the google can anyone guide me why it is happening and how to fix this issue.

I have many images in my wordpress media library with different names such as:

1. abcd-images
2. bold-images
3. 123

Now what is happening i saw in google site:example.com so i found auto created 70 new pages like this www.example.com/abcd-images ,  www.example.com/bold-images, www.example.com/123 and when i went into my WP dashboard so i didnt find any post created there, even i checked my SEO yoast xml file there is no found.I don't know how it is created and how it got indexed in search engine.

Now please assist me why it happening and how can i fix this issue.

I would be highly thankful to you guys and this platform.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress by default creates a single page for each attachment that you have on your site. This includes images, audio/video files, pdfs, etc.

If you are already using WordPress SEO by Yoast plugin, then go to your SEO > Permalinks options page. All you have to do is check the box next to “Redirect attachment URL’s to parent post URL”. This will redirect users arriving at attachment pages to the parent post.